# CSS scale pixel size up and down based on screen size

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have pixel details (font-size and component width and height in px) for one screen size for example 800x600 screen size. I want to implement an HTML page that can run on different screen sizes. **But on the 800x600 screen size, it should fit/have exactly the same given pixel size.**

```
Example: 
font-size: 16px -- On 800x600 screen size.    
font-size: 24px -- 16px scale to 24px on xxxxxx screen size
```

I have explored `vw, vh` but it depends on the container width/height, I need to calculate the `px` size to `vw/vh` size.
Also, the size in percentage needs to be converted using pixel size.
Is there something inbuilt in CSS that we can use?

Comment: How about `@media only screen and (width: 800px) and (height: 600px) { font-size: 16px; }` for 800x600px? Also, for other screen sizes, what is the exact formula you are looking for (even if not possible to compute currently)?

Comment: yeah, you should use media queries and there's no way to convert vw to px using pure css.

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
  --font-size-min: 16;
  --font-size-max: 24;
    
  --width-min: 800;
  --width-max: 1920;
  
  --font-size-delta: calc(var(--font-size-max) - var(--font-size-min));
  --font-size-min-px: calc(1px * var(--font-size-min));
  --width-delta: calc(var(--width-max) - var(--width-min));
  --width-min-px: calc(1px * var(--width-min));
  --width-delta-px: calc(1px * var(--width-delta));
  --width-lower: calc(100vw - var(--width-min-px));
  --width-limit: min(max(var(--width-lower), 0px), var(--width-delta-px));
  --scale-ratio: calc(var(--font-size-delta) / var(--width-delta));
  --font-size-zero: calc(var(--width-limit) * var(--scale-ratio));
  
  --font-size: calc(var(--font-size-zero) + var(--font-size-min-px));
}
body {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
```

This is set up to make the font size 16px at a view width of 800px and a font size of 24px at a view width of 1920px. It is also capped at both ends and scaled in between.

Generally, you need to pick either width *or* height to match against. The defacto standard is to use width and that's what I've done here.

This does the necessary computations entirely in CSS. `--font-size-*` and `--width-*` must be dimensionless units; the remaining variables take care of converting them to `px` units.

A lot of this can be optimized. I left it like this so that it's clearer as to what's going on.

Note: `min()` and `max()` are sort of newish additions to CSS. I know of at least one uncommon browser that they don't work with (though there's an update for it planned Soon™). Those parts could be refactored to use `@media` instead.

Comment: no one can verify your answer without running it and snippet is created for such purpose but well ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Converting to a snippet doesn't enhance the answer because the code is dependent on being able to adjust your view width within a large range.

Comment: and since the OP is asking for such *large* range then I suppose he is able to do it and most of us can do since 800px isn't that large. We also have the responsive tab where we can define any screen size.